# General failure. Please try again. Server may be unavailable (2013)

Tags: blackberry-webworks

So today, whenever I try to sign My Blackberry app using the WebWorks packager, I get this error...

"General failure. Please try again. Server may be unavailable".

My proxy settings have not changed and I have been using the same command line instruction with success before.

I've also checked the status of the Blackberry signing server using the following link...

http://isthesigningserverdown.com/chart/index.php?sigType=RBB or RCR or RRT

And everything appears to be online!

So, where could I be going wrong? Here's the command line instruction I've been using. First, I navigate to my Blackberry build folder and run the following instruction against it...

```
bbwp appname.zip –g <password> –o z:\projects\appname\signed
```

It goes through through parsing the various elements. The signing tool pops up and then the error is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a couple of days of banging my head against the wall-the answer finally came to me. I'm on a MAC but am also using a Windows virtual machine for Blackberry developement, which is running on another network altogether and this specific network is using a firewall, which, according to the network administrator, is currently experiencing a severe technical problem.

The way round it was to sign my Blackberry app using configured proxy settings to communicate with the signing server and viola! It worked!

Comment: Can you share your proxy settings?